# Sharing SASS vars between files, when file name is unknown

Tags: css, sass

This is my stylesheet declaration code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="username-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
```

"username-theme.css" filename vary, ie john123-theme.css or jenifer-theme.css

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

in my layout.scss I want to use following code:

```
body{color:$theme-color}
```

where `$theme-color` comes from `john123-theme.scss`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4).

so you can have a file smth like **_variables.scss** with your variables defined and then in your **layout.scss** you will include it like

```
@import 'variables';
```

so all the variables will be available there.

Comment: I don't have _variables.scss, because I mantain multiple themes at the same time, and the server code will replace username-theme.scss with ie artur-theme.scss. I have physically 10 themes at the same time but include only the relevant one.

Comment: I do not see the problem to create it and share with import in those files where you need it. Maybe i'm missing something here.

Comment: If I had the _variables.scss file with some values, and then another scss, ie _user-theme.scss that overrides the _variables.scss values will the user-theme override the _variables.scss? I cannot use "@import user-theme" because I dont render the scss files serverside and I dont know what user is logged in.

Comment: @thanks yuyokk - what I'm trying to accomplish seems to be a bad pattern

Answer (score 0):

You could try importing the other way, and at the end of your user stylesheet, import layout.scss. as long as the variable is defined before the import, it's value will be used in the layout.scss contents. Then you'll just have to link the user css file into the page, because it now includes everything you had in layout.scss. ex:

**_layout.scss**

```
body{color:$theme-color}
```

**username-theme.scss**

```
//define variable
$theme-color: #fff;

//import 
@import "layout";
```

Comment: I've actually seen something similar to this pattern in a lot of sass frameworks or normalize type things. http://bitters.bourbon.io/ here's an example